# UIButton set border of specific sides

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to set a UIButton's border widths to different values, similar to CSS like `border-width: 0 1px 0 0` or `border-right-width: 1px`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a standard `UIButton`, no. You'll have to use a custom button and create images that match your desired design.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible using APIs

Comment: Actually, it does directly answer the question that was posed.